# Best way to use Entity Framework (Database First , Model First , Code First)

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, database-first

I Am Confused To Choose Way Of Use Entity Framework.

What's Differents In These Ways (Database First , Model First , Code First) ?

I Just Started A Medium Project (This Project In ASP.NET MVC And Likely MIS & CRM)

Thanks For Helping Me.

Comment: My Project was Completed on First of This year (2016) =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *best* way. All depends on approach you use to develop application.

If you are doing Domain-Driven Design and you start from business logic with entities considered as persistence ignorant, then Code First is obviously your way (because you write code before adding persistence).

If you already have existing database or you use data-first approach (when database structure designed before code is written) then Database First is your choice.